# Landing page as in games (splitted to 3 columns)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw some JS library for animation like that:
[how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsK6j.png)

Yes, I know I rock in Paint :D

I'm looking for such script for 2 days and I cannot find it. To be honest I would rather get working **responsive** version rather than write it myself.

Does anyone have such script?

Comment: just use `skewx` you will see the magic http://jsfiddle.net/gyofukr1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give any more information about what you want to achieve? You mentioned animation but your image didn't explain what's being animated.

If you just wanted a menu on top and the slanted images on the bottom, you could definitely do that with plain HTML and CSS...

In html:

```
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        //Put some stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        //Put a bunch of <image> tags here with an href for the links and a div with class "image".
    </div>
</body>
```

In CSS:

```
.menu{
    /* Style stuff for the menu*/
}
.images{
    clear:both; 
}
.image{
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
    float:left;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
```

As long as your images are slanted, have a transparent background and are ordered correctly, and the distance horizontally from the bottom right corner to the bottom top corner is 20px, they should align on top of each other with a border.

You could also use canvas in javascript and do something like ctx.drawImage() to draw the grid of images and ctx.setTransform()to slant them.

-Edit- Or if you don't care much for browsers below IE10 you could just snip out the margins and use transform: translate() in your image div to skew them, then you wouldn't need transparency or to skew the images, just align them.

Comment: I want to slice page below menu to oblique parts (div's ?) with some images. After hovering on those div's, image bounce up and down (or scroll/slide etc.). I'm sure I saw something like that in some opensource lib but I dont remember the name...

Comment: You can do it manually using the previously mentioned javascript/whatever js library you want by making a full sized canvas. Just set the transform to skew the images, and the x and y to different values based on time in drawimage or transform using canvas.addEventListener(mouseover, setoffset);